# Flower identification?

Tags: identification, flowers, propagation, reproduction

Can someone identify this plant?
Also, how does one propagate this plant to a pot?

Ive noticed that this flower grows from the trunk?

This flower also grows in Florida.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's a [phaelenopsis orchid](https://getbusygardening.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/white-phalaenopsis-orchid-flowers.jpg). It's not growing from the trunk. If the plant is in a garden, then the roots have probably been attached to the trunk to mimic the way in which it grows in the wild. If not, then they probably look something [like this](https://getbusygardening.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/orchid-roots-attached-to-a-tree-branch.webp).